# A confusion about explicit specialization for member of class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<class T> struct A {
  struct B { };
  template<class U> struct C { 
      void show();
  };
};

template<>
template<>
void A<int>::C<int>::show(){  //#1

}

int main(){

}
```

Consider the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/YcWs4d),  At `#1`, it's an explicit specialization definition for member of member class template. Some rules will be applied to it as the following specified:

[temp.expl.spec#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#5)

> A member of an explicitly specialized class is not implicitly instantiated from the member declaration of the class template; instead, the member of the class template specialization shall itself be explicitly defined if its definition is required. **In this case, the definition of the class template explicit specialization shall be in scope at the point at which the member is defined**. The definition of an explicitly specialized class is unrelated to the definition of a generated specialization. That is, its members need not have the same names, types, etc. as the members of a generated specialization. Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the template<> syntax. The same is true when defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class. However, template<> is used in defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class template that is specialized as a class template.

Firstly, what's `explicitly specialized class`? Does it refer to the entity which has explicit specialization declaration? It seems to it doesn't mean it, please look at the example in `Explicitly specialized class` part

```cpp
template<> template<> class A<int>::B<double>;
```

According to that example, `A<int>` within the explicit specialization for member can be called a `explicitly specialized class`. So, In my first example `A<int>` and `C<int>` are all `explicitly specialized class`? I'm not sure. I feel the phrase `explicitly specialized class` is not clear in this section.

Please note the emphasized part, it means the enclosing class template explicit specialization shall appear in the same scope as that of explicit specialization definition for its member.  The member is defined in global scope but there's no any explicit specialization definition for `A<int>` or `C<int>` that appears in the global scope. How to interpret this?

By the way, as a opposite example:

```cpp
template<class T> struct A {
  struct B { };
  template<class U> struct C { 
      void show();
  };
};

template<>
template<typename U>
struct A<int>::C{  //#2
    void show();
};

template<>
template<typename U>
void A<int>::C<U>::show(){  //#3

}

int main(){

}
```

why such code is required an explicit specialization for class template `C` before `#3`, what's the difference between such two examples?

#### Explicitly specialized class

The phrase "explicitly specialized class" is unclear in this section,

[temp.expl.spec#15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#15)

> A member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class templates. In an explicit specialization for such a member, the member declaration shall be preceded by a template<> for each enclosing class template that is **explicitly specialized**.

```
[ Example:  
template<class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    void mf();
  };
};
template<> template<> class A<int>::B<double>;
template<> template<> void A<char>::B<char>::mf();
— end example ]
```

what's the `explicitly specialized class` mean, Is it refer to an entity that have a explicit specialization declaration or something others?  It seems to no explicit specialization for `A<int>` in the above example.

Comment: Why do you cite that paragraph? Where is an explicitly specialized class in your code?

Comment: There are several things missing to make that quote relevant. It says that if you have an explicit class template specialization (which you don't) and a member of that specialization needs a definition the class template must be in scope (not in the same scope, just visible) as the member definition.

Comment: Your code is covered by the previous paragraph.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The wording `explicitly specialized` is not clear in this section, please see [temp.expl.spec#15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#15), The example does not contain any `enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized`

Comment: @super Firstly, the first quote says `A member of an explicitly specialized class...`,  Is the `show`  a member of `explicitly specialized class C<int>`? It seems to the  phrase "explicitly specialized class" is not clear. what's it?

Comment: @jackX You are providing a explicit full specialization for a member function of a class template. The class template however does not have any explicit specialization.

Comment: @super How do you interpret the example in this rule [temp.expl.spec#15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#15), Note the sentence `for each enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized.`, It seems to there's no any explicit specialization for `A<int>` or `B<char>` in that example.

Comment: @jackX I think it is http://wg21.link/cwg529

Comment: @jackX I interpret it as `mf` is being explicitly specialized for `A<char>` and `B<char>`. Hence `A<char>` and `B<char>` are explicitly specialized in that declaration. There is no explicit class template specialization.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The proposal means `explicit specialized` refer to an entity declared by explicit specialization declaration, Right? Hence the first quote is used to constraint such member that declared in the explicit specialization declaration of its enclosing template class, Right?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer How about the second example, How to interpret this. why the explicit specialization for class template `C` must be provided in the scope at the point at which the member `show` defined?  Could you leave an answers in this question, bro?

Answer (score 0):

There is no confusion there, you have to parse those statements (C++ and English) according to their grammatical structure.  Source code is  description of program in language understandable for humans. Programming language is a tool of human cooperation.

CWG529 removed  need to understand intuitively by changing wording to explain order and content of template-ids.

Here you declared template of class A with template parameter T, which contains class B and a nested declaration of template class C with template parameter U, which contains a method `show()`:

```
template<class T> struct A {
  struct B { };
  template<class U> struct C { 
      void show();
  };
};
```

Here you declared, that for explicitly specialized template class A (which required to have it declared first) with `T = int` that there is a template class C which contains method `show()`

```
template<>
template<typename U>
struct A<int>::C{  //#2
    void show();
};
```

This declaration doesn't contradict previous one, but because it's a specialization of class A, it may expand it! You can do this:

```
template<>
template<typename U>
struct A<int>::C{  //#4
    void hide();
};
```

Which means that for any A with `T=int`,   there is a template class C that got member `hide()`. But other A's will have template class C with member `show()`. What previous statement did that it removed any doubts about content of C for this A's specialization.

Now this only defines member function `show()` for all C's contained in `A<int>`:

```
template<>
template<typename U>
void A<int>::C<U>::show(){  //#3

}
```

You don't have an explicit specialization of C here, which is an enclosing class for `show()`. the memeber id `show()` is preceded by an unspecialized template-id `template<typename U>` ... `C<U>`.  There is only a definition of member function but it requires a visible declaration of that template C - the #2 part. The visibility may be attained by various means and "the scope" mentioned is generalized description of it.

Omitting part #2 would be a semantic equivalent of writing:

```
class C;

void C::show() { // ill-formed - C is an incomplete type.
}
```

We would  know that all of A's contain some class C, but we don't have a complete definition for that particular C in specialized `A<int>` (and it may be different).

This statement actually states that specialization `C<int>`nested in specialization `A<int>` contains `show()`

```
template<>
template<>
void A<int>::C<int>::show(){  //#1

}
```

Any possibility of contradiction, ambiguity or uncertainty (aside from undefined behavior) are leading to ill-formed code and rules are meant to form the framework of limitations against which the code should be checked. With absence of #2, the #3 at some point could be followed by #4, then the #3 statement would become illegal and thus it is deemed as such. #2 and #4 at same time would be two definitions of same thing which also leads either to ill-formed code if they are present in same unit, or they would lead to undefined behavior if they are present in separate units within program.

Comment: It seems to you haven't interpret these code from LanguageLawyer point. In actually the phrase `explicit specialized` is unclear in [temp.expl.spec] section, and http://wg21.link/cwg529 clarifies for it.

Comment: and why `Omitting part #2 would be a semantic equivalent of writing...`? The definition of class template `C` has defined in your first code. why it's incomplete? as a opposite example, why I need not to define  `template<>
template<typename U>
struct A<int>::C{  //#2
    void show();
};` for  `void A<int>::C<int>::show()` in my example?

Comment: @jackX that was definition for class C in class template A. But you're trying to define member for class template C nested in in explicitly specialized `A<int>` without defining that class template, it's not a specialization of member of class template `A<int>:C`. `void A<int>::C<int>::show()` variant is allowed by temp.expl.spec#15 (and cwg529 removes factor of intuitive understanding of what it means), because it is a specialization

Comment: @jackX the difference similar with between `void foo(class C& a)` and `void foo(C& a)`? First also forward-declares class C. templates can't be forward declared, but `temp.expl.spec#15` explicitly allows to declare that such specialization exist. In variant in question, it's unknown. For all we know `A<int>` may be a `template<> A<int> {};` - an empty class, or `A<int>::C` can  be an empty class.

Comment: No.  Such case `void A<int>::C<int>::show()` is permitted by [temp.expl.spec#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#4) where specialization `A<int>` and `C<int>` all cause `implicitly instantiation`.   And explicit specialization for member `void A<int>::C<U>::show()` shall obey [temp.expl.spec#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#5) rule, that is, the explicit specialization declaration for enclosing class template `C` shall be appear in the scope at point at which the member is defined.